# What if persons involved in the accident with the same Insurance company?

Tags: insurance, damages, accident

I really don't know how to ask this question properly, but this is my situation. Last week, a car rear-ended me while I was waiting to make a left turn, because there was oncoming traffic. It was just my luck that he and I are with the same insurance company, Progressive. I thought since we both are insured by the same car insurance company, the whole process would go smoothly and I will be able to get my car fixed up in one week using the other guy's insurance policy. However, Progressive told me I can't depend or rely on the other guy's insurance for it may or may not be good and that they can't tell me the EXACT reason, even though Progressive told me that this accident is his FAULT. So, I have to use my insurance to fix the damage and pay a $1,000 dollar deductible. I simply don't like how Progressive is handling this accident nor do I want to pay them $1,000. I want Progressive to pick up the bill and pay for the whole damages to my car. I have been with Progressive since 2003 and they have been auto-withdrawing the premium straight out of my bank account since 2003. So, what are my options?

Comment: And your jurisdiction is?

Comment: @DaleM ??? I am the owner of my car driving at the time of the accident and I am fully covered by my insurance. The idea that now this accident caused by the uninsured driver will cost me money ($1,000) out of my pocket is bit too much. Why should I be penalized for his mistake. He pretty much was tailgating me. He rear ended me as soon as I slowed down to make the left turn... He must not been paying attention to the road. He most likely was on his phone texting...

Answer (score 7):

You have been told that the other person's insurance may not be valid. Why it may not doesn't really matter, perhaps the other person didn't pay premiums or lied on an application. So the situation is much the same as if the other person is uninsured or under insured. Your p[olicy must cover things. And your policy has a deductible. So you have to pay the deductable amount. That is what a deductible is, the amount  that you must pay before your policy coverage kicks in. The lower it is, the higher your premium is. You don't have any choice about that.

Depending on your jurisdiction, you may be able to sue the other person involved in the accident, and get that person to pay. Your insurance company might do this for you, but if they won't you would have to hire a lawyer yourself to do that. Such a lawyer could get all the details of your case, and advise you of your options.